# Prove $\sum_{d|n} \frac{\Phi(d)}{d} = \prod_{i=1}^r (1 + a_i - \frac{a_i}{p_i})$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function, mobius-inversion

I want to prove $\sum_{d|n} \frac{\Phi(d)}{d} = \prod_{i=1}^r (1 + a_i(1 - \frac{1}{p_i}))$, where $\Phi(n)$ is the Euler phi function and given the prime factorisation $n = \prod_{i=1}^r p_i^{a_i} $.

My instinct says to use the Möbius inversion formula, but I am struggling to identify the functions $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ that will allow me to prove this. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that with your factorization we get for example

$$\sum_{d|n} d =
\prod_{q=1}^r (1+p_q+p_q^2+\cdots+p_q^{a_q})$$

Now we have with the product ranging over prime divisors that

$$\frac{\varphi(d)}{d} = \prod_{p|d} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right).$$

Using the same scheme again we thus obtain

$$\sum_{d|n} \frac{\varphi(d)}{d} =
\prod_{q=1}^r
\left(1 + \left(1-\frac{1}{p_q}\right) +
\left(1-\frac{1}{p_q}\right) +  \cdots
+ \left(1-\frac{1}{p_q}\right) \right)$$

where the sum contains $a_q$ terms. This yields

$$\prod_{q=1}^r
\left(1 + a_q \left(1-\frac{1}{p_q}\right)\right)$$

which  is the  claim.  Here  we use  the fact  that $\varphi(d)/d$  is
multiplicative   and   so  is   $\alpha\star   1$   with  $\alpha$   a
multiplicative function as pointed out by M. Cohen.

Comment: This might have an obvious answer, but how do we know that $\sum_{d|n} d = \prod_{q=1}^r (1 + p_q + {p_q}^2) + ... + {p_q}^{a_q}) $?

Comment: Choose a path through the product to cover all terms. This means makng one choice for $q=1$, another for $q=2$ and so on, for $r$ choices altogether. We will produce all divisors by proceeding in this manner, which means that we select the unique power of $p_q$ dividing $d.$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your
$\Phi$
is actually the
Euler $\phi$ function,
use the fact that,
since
$\phi$ is a multiplicative
function,
so is
$\sum_{d | n}\dfrac{\phi(d)}{d}$.

Then you only need to prove it for
$p^a$.